# kotlin StateFlow doesn't respond on change in state in some cases

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

Despite on the state of the `StateFlow` has been updated `StateFlow` `collect{}` is not called.

One of the possible reason might be it doesn't pass `equality` check. So implemented custom `equality` check to make sure changes in the field I am interested in are considered during `equality` check. In addition I run trough debugger to understand situation better and it shown `compareAndSet(`) method has been called and state has been updated.

Although this changes doesn't lead to updating state on subscriber.

The model looks like this:

```
data class Model(
    var ownerProfile: PersonProfile? = null,
    val counterpartyProfile: PersonProfile? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val errors: List<String> = emptyList()
)
```

Here is the request:

```
    repository.getContacts(
        contact = state.value.ownerProfile!!.contact,
        secret = state.value.ownerProfile!!.secret,
        serviceId = serviceId
    )
        .onStart {state.update { state -> state.copy(isLoading = true) } }
        .collect { it ->
            processResponse(it)
        }

private fun processResponse(response: PersonRepository.Response<PersonProfile>) {
    when (response) {
        is PersonRepository.Response.Data -> {
            state.update { state ->
                state.copy(
                    counterpartyProfile = response.data,
                    isLoading = false)
            }
        } 
...
```

And here is subscriber:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.uiState.collect { it ->
        if (it.errors.isNotEmpty()) {
            showErrorDialog(it.errors.first())
        }
        binding.name = it.counterpartyProfile?.name
        binding.contact = it.counterpartyProfile?.contact
    }
}
```

Full code available in the [repo](https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/8a8257ee5630e1c355224f5afb881529aa4499b1/mobile%20client/app/src/main/java/ru/home/swap/ui/contacts/ContactsViewModel.kt).

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
state.update { state ->
    state.copy() 
}
state.value.ownerProfile = it
```

You are updating state firstly with the copy of the same state and only later setting the property of newly copied state.
You need to do this in one go, like this:

```
state.update { state ->
    state.copy().apply { ownerProfile = it } 
}
```

Changing properties of `state.value` will not be reflected in the collector.

Comment: Thank you for spot it. Not sure regarding cause of why it was left as this -- this code is meaningless. However it doesn't solve the issue I state in the origin question.

Comment: Does breakpoint stop inside viewModel.uiState.collect {} ?

Comment: It stops, but better question is when it stops :) ViewModel state has been changed several times and final time when it changes (open 2nd different contact) it doesn't trigger collect - breakpoint doesn't stop inside viewModel.uiState.collect {} in your words

Comment: What is important is previous state and a new state (incoming object) are two different states. It _should_ trigger collect.

Comment: Try to set the state to null just before you set it to new value (and make object nullable, so that you will be able to set it to null).

Comment: I have checked it. Its state has been updated to null and in the next step reassigned to the new value. However it doesn't trigger collect. Thank you for your attempts to help, I will continue work on this.

Comment: Now that you have all this, try to remove custom hashCode and equals overrides.

Comment: I think about the issue might lies in context it is used. Firstly I try to isolate current piece of code from the rest of the app and frameworks. When I omit dagger in work with ViewModel I was able to solve this issue. Next step is to find out the root cause of the issue